# Did Gen. Patton say "We defeated the wrong enemy?"

Tags: united-states, russia, world-war-ii, nazi-germany

I've seen this quote in various far-right memes. Supposedly, Gen. George S. Patton, upon taking control of Berlin in 1945, said "We defeated the wrong enemy." The Communists, one supposes, were the right enemy. Is it an authentic quotation?

Comment: WikiQuote has nothing https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_S._Patton. BTW many right wing sites suggest he was referring to Jews, not communists.

Comment: Compare Churchill; "we've slaughtered the wrong pig". He was not so much referring to generic communists as to Soviet Russia in the hands of Stalin.

Comment: Did Patton every even go to Berlin - he definitely was not in control of it - He was military governer of Bohemia

Comment: @Mark of  Bavaria

Comment: In the 1970 movie "Patton" he says "Up until now we've been fighting the wrong people" https://books.google.com/books?id=ivx-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA63&dq=%22fighting+the+wrong+people%22+patton&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLhKeNksXQAhXp24MKHXlwCrIQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22fighting%20the%20wrong%20people%22%20patton&f=false

Comment: Neonazi videos that pop up when you google for this phrase seem to have a lot of rather... less than pleasant reputed Patton quotes.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll submit an answer. I don't know whether Patton ever spoke those words, but he certainly didn't say them "upon taking control of Berlin" - the Russians took control of Berlin. They continued west until they met the western allies at what became the border between East Germany and West Germany. The US, UK, and France demanded that Berlin be administered jointly by all four allies; hence West Berlin, subsequently walled in by the Soviets.

Comment: Right, but Mark already commented that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is at least an accurate paraphrase:

The 1975 [Bodyguard of Lies Volume II](https://books.google.com/books?id=2RFmAPmDgW0C&q=eisenhower%20%20patton%20relieved%20of%20command%20wrong%20enemy&dq=eisenhower%20%20patton%20relieved%20of%20command%20wrong%20enemy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim09WY9cPQAhWBfCYKHbyYD94Q6AEIGzAA) says:

> Patton was relieved of command of the 3rd Army by Eisenhower just after the end of the war for stating publicly that America had been fighting the wrong enemy— Germany instead of Russia

According to the 1987 book [Cannon fodder: growing up for Vietnam](https://books.google.com/books?id=32DxAAAAMAAJ&q=patton%20bastards%20%22wrong%20enemy%22&dq=patton%20bastards%20%22wrong%20enemy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2vrGEkMTQAhVL0WMKHXwACEUQ6AEIGjAB) the exact quote is:

> We may have been fighting the wrong enemy (Germany) all along. But while we're here (on 
>   the Soviet border), we should go after the bastards now, 'cause we're gonna have to fight 'em eventually.

The 1953 article "We Called Him Uncle Georgie", originally published in [The National Guardsman](https://books.google.com/books?id=LXDfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22I%20think%20we've%20been%20fighting%20the%20wrong%20people%20all%20this%20time%22&dq=%22I%20think%20we've%20been%20fighting%20the%20wrong%20people%20all%20this%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq9dnbicXQAhWe0YMKHXN7DbAQ6AEIHjAA) and reprinted in [V.F.W. Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=MakMAQAAMAAJ&q=%22I%20think%20we've%20been%20fighting%20the%20wrong%20people%20all%20this%20time%22&dq=%22I%20think%20we've%20been%20fighting%20the%20wrong%20people%20all%20this%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq9dnbicXQAhWe0YMKHXN7DbAQ6AEIIjAB) and Quartermaster Review XXXIII, about Patton by Red Cross worker Betty South, who had direct access to the general at the relavent time, says:

> When he went to Berlin to receive the kiss of death from the Russians he remarked shortly, "I think we've been fighting the wrong people all this time, but I've oiled my belly so I can stay with them on the Vodka. My front will be as good as theirs."

Another related exact quote is:

> the Germans are the only decent people left in Europe. It's a choice between them and the Russians. I prefer the Germans.

[Displaced Persons: The Liberation and Abuse of Holocaust Survivors](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jx_AOBjydlEC&pg=PA38&dq=it's%20a%20choice%20between%20them%20and%20the%20russians.%20i%20prefer%20the%20germans.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicgfz9gMTQAhWBUSYKHRheCyUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=it's%20a%20choice%20between%20them%20and%20the%20russians.%20i%20prefer%20the%20germans.%22&f=false)